# Did anyone ever bring up the Asgard's resemblance to the legendary Greys?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

The Asgard are depicted as humanity's friend against the Goa'uld, yet they look suspiciously similar to creatures accused of abducting humans for experiments (including rectal probes).

I can understand Teal'c or Jonas not making the connection since they come from other planets but shouldn't the similarities have raised eyebrows from O'Neil, Carter or the rest of the SGC?

Comment: Daniel Jackson commented on the resemblance not long after we first see Thor's true appearance. We also learn that the Asgard have experimented on humans in the past, while the rogue Asgard Loki is still doing so in modern times.

Comment: BTW, I'm guessing no one told the SG1 writers Asgard was a place, the gods inhabiting it were the Aesir- just thought somebody should point that out.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, Jack and Daniel make an observation about it very early in the series. Then again another reference is made during the episode (S07E03 "Fragile Balance") with Loki and the clone of Jack that is aged wrong.

> LOKI: I am a scientist, a former geneticist with the Asgard Ruling Council.
>
> CARTER: Former?
>
> LOKI: I was stripped of my stature after I was caught performing **unsanctioned experiments on humans**.
>
> O'NEILL: ***What? You've got sanctioned ones?***

Referring to the stories of human abduction by Greys.

Comment: Quotes soon, mobile.

Comment: Ooh. I may beat you to it. On my way home now

Comment: @Richard you did, but I found another one

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is discussed in-universe on a couple of occasions.

> **CARTER:** *Daniel, this is uncanny. It looks just like the descriptions of the Roswell Greys back home.*
>
> **DANIEL:** *I guess there's some truth to those stories after all.*
>
> **CARTER:** *You think the Asgards may have visited Earth?*
>
> **DANIEL:** *Why not?*
>
> <sub>[*SG-1*: "Thor's Chariot"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/2.06_%22Thor%27s_Chariot%22_Transcript)</sub>

and

> **SAMANTHA:** *Well, this is incredible. If the Asgard could design this to give the Gate extra juice, then they're just the little green
> men we're looking for.*
>
> **O'NEILL:** *They're grey actually. Roswell grey, to be exact.*
>
> <sub>[*SG-1*: "Point of View"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/index.php/3.06_%22Point_Of_View%22_Transcript)</sub>

---

Interestingly, the subject of the Roswell incident was a key part of the Fandemonium novel [*Stargate SG-1: Roswell*](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1:_Roswell), which featured time-travel and extensive involvement/meddling by the Asgard Loki in Earth's history. Without wishing to spoil the plotline, it turns out that the Roswell greys were

> a set of Asgard-Human hybrids who died in their escape pods when they crash-landed at Roswell, New Mexico.